# HTML tags in prompt (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I need to use HTML tags in the prompt in JavaScript. It is possible to do this?

For example:

```
var x = prompt ("<img src = 'image.png'>");
```

Comment: Do you want to setup default value or to customize the view of the prompt? First one - yes (but it is a second argument of the function 'prompt'), second - no, create a 'replacement' of the modal window with javascript/css/html Like this one - http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Comment: No, not possible. Use a library to fake a modal prompt.